# Change local to global variable does not work

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am planning to centralize all variables, thus set them to global variables residing outside of the templates. As described below the exact same variable works if adding it locally inside the template. The code is heavily minmized to fit an SO question. The amount of global variables will be greater.

**Problem:**

Moving the variable outside of template and use it as global variable does not return expected result.

You find the same code in this [xsltfiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaRX/3).

---

Code:

**Data (JSON):**

```
<data>
{
  "report": {
    "facts": [
      {
        "xbrl:concept": "se:CompanyName",
        "value": "Great Company Ltd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  
  <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->
    
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Global variable -->
    
    <xsl:variable name="headings"  select="//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:CompanyName']/../*[@key='value']"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="//*[@key='facts']">
        <!-- Local variable works when uncommented -->
        <!--<xsl:variable name="headings"  select="//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:CompanyName']/../*[@key='value']"/>-->
        <xsl:value-of select="$headings"/>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

**Expected result:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Great Company Ltd`

Comment: Martin Honnen has explain why your change doesn't work, but I would also take a step back and ask what you are trying to achieve. As in most programming languages, global variables in XSLT are best avoided when you can: they reduce the reusability of your code.

Comment: By using parsed JSON data in XSLT the select strings becomes rather long and that affects overview and visibility of code especially when potentially handing over code to another developer. The plan and what I was looking to achieve was to have the select string to be part of global variables, thus having the long select string grouped in one XSLT file. Further on, by having all variables grouped I wanted to see if I could shrink the string length.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to make more use of functions rather than variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy "I am planning to centralize all variables, thus set them to global variables residing outside of the templates." doesn't make any sense, a global variable is evaluated relative to the global context item, any local variable is evaluated relative to the context item of the template or further nested instructions in the template.

So your global attempt `<xsl:variable name="headings" select="//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:CompanyName']/../*[@key='value']"/>` would look for an element with attribute `key` being `xbrl:concept` in the global context item which, as far as I understand, is your document with a `data` element containing some JSON. That document doesn't have any such element, obviously.

It is doubtful that all your paths will be absolute path starting with `//` from the root and looking anywhere in the document but currently you don't even have the right root for your intent to use "global variables".

You could try e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="json-xml-doc" select="json-to-xml(data)"/>
```

and then use e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="headings" select="$json-xml-doc//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:CompanyName']/../*[@key='value']"/>
```

but I wouldn't recommend that, in the end, I think, most lookup expression are easier to write, read and maintain, shorter to read, understand and maintain and probably often more efficient if they are relative to your context item.